# Is this possible to add async function result into table row?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-client-side

I'm creating web-client for my REST API, and I want to add a field to my table containing result of async function.

```
@foreach(Product item in products)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@item.Name</th>
                <th>@item.Amount</th>
                <th>@GetUnit(item.UnitID).Result</th>
                <th>@item.PriceNetto</th>
            </tr>
        }


async Task<string> GetUnit(Guid id)
{
    string a = "https://localhost:5001/api/Units/";
    a += id.ToString();
    var temp = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Unit>(a); //it fails here
    return temp.Name;
}
```

In short I have a list of products and items on the list have "UnitID" property which I use to make a GET request. When I put anywhere in code `.Result` after my async function result Visual Studio's debugger just skip the line responsible for calling the API and 'bricks' whole app without any error nor exception. Then I have to restart the project.

I tried to create second function only for returning `GetUnit(id).Result` but it gave nothing. I tried to return whole Unit object and then in the table `GetUnit(item.UnitID).Name` but it was just representing object (I guess...). I seems like all I need is do it with `.Result` but when I do it doesn't work.

My API is made with .Net Core 2.2 and my client is made with .Net Core 3.0 (Blazor template). Is this a bug or I just can't do it that way? Thanks.

Comment: Can you await your method in the table instead of using .Result? Like `<th>@(await GetUnit(item.UnitID))</th>`

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, you can't do that way.In blazor,you could get all data in `OnInitializedAsync` instead.Store all `Name` in a string List and display the list data in view based index.For example:

```
@code {

    private List<string> listItems = new List<string>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //get products

        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            string a = "https://localhost:5001/api/Units/";
            a += product.UnitID.ToString();
            var temp = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Unit>(a); 

           listItems.Add(temp.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Razor

```
@{  int i = 0;}
@foreach(Product item in products)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>@item.Name</th>
            <th>@item.Amount</th>
            <th>  @listItems[i] </th>
            <th>@item.PriceNetto</th>
        </tr>
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't need to do it.i recommand to call it in async action,like below :
**razor focus on view,controller/model focus on data.**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction(Guid id)
{
    var products = ..;
    foreach (var item in products)
    {
        p.UnitID = await GetUnit(item.UnitID);
    }
    return View(products);
}

private async Task<string> GetUnit(Guid id)
{
    string a = "https://localhost:5001/api/Units/";
    a += id.ToString();
    var temp = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Unit>(a); //it fails here
    return temp.Name;
}

public class Product 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public decimal Amount { get; set; } 
    public string UnitID { get; set; }  
    public string PriceNetto { get; set; }  
}
```